# RSS Rome not working due to JDOM dependency

Tags: rss, dependencies, jdom, rome

I am trying to get ROM RSS to work and the JDOM dependency is not working with it. Apparently this is because the JDOM libraries use the package org.jdom2.Document type classes not the org.jdom.Document classes that Rome is expecting. Apparently Rome is ancient and has not been maintained since 2009.

What is the solution here? Do I need to dredge up some ancient version of JDOM that Rome is actually compatible with or is there an alternative to Rome that has been maintained within the current decade and can work with the latest JDOM releases?

Comment: ROM RSS or Rome RSS? https://github.com/rometools/rome/commits/master/pom.xml uses JDOM 2.x so shoudl be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The latest releases of ROME can be found here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Crometools

We had to change the groupId some time ago